# Glassfish stops when I close putty window or if putty is inactive

Tags: linux, glassfish

I have Glassfish up and running on a Linux machine.

I am using putty to connect to that machine.

I start the domain using

```
/opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain --verbose
```

The instant I close the putty window or putty is inactive the Glassfish instance is no longer running.

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are starting the server in verbose mode with the flag `--verbose` and when you close the putty session the server is stopped. So if you don't want that behavior you must start the domain without the verbose flag.

```
/opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
```